# Prove boundedness of origin sequence from boundedness of subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to prove the following theorem.

> > If $\{a_n\}$ is monotonic increasing real sequence and its certain subsequence $\{a_p\}$ is bounded, then the origin sequence $\{a_n\}$ is also bounded.

Help me prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M > 0$ such that $|a_{p_n}| \le M$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$. Since $p_n \ge n$ for all $n$ and $\{a_n\}$ is monotonic increasing, $a_n \le a_{p_n} \le M$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$. Thus $a_1 \le a_n \le M$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$. In particular, $\{a_n\}$ is bounded.